# How to configure zend and work in php using codeIgniter and zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter

I am working in windows and unziped php in c:/php and made require changes in php.ini file. And configure php with IIS also. 
I've also configure codeIgniter and its up and running.

Now i have to add zend with php.Please anyone tell me how to configure zend framework ?

And how can i create a sample in php using codeIgniter and zend as i have recently started with php?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.  Personally I just used spl_autoload_register() with an autoloading function which loads zend framework libraries for me.  You can also just include the necessary zend files that are needed for the zend libraries you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS running with php then you are all set. Just follow the installation instructions in the documentation.